# How to assert unauthenticated?

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-7

In my controller constructor I have middleware auth. How do I assert that somebody is not authenticated in tests? Right now I'm getting Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException and the only way to make test positive is to add

```
$this->expectException('Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException')
```

in the beginning. I saw solutions like using withoutExceptionHandling() in the beginning of test or using assertUnauthorized() but that doesn't change anything.

Is there a better way?

I'm using Laravel 7.2.2 and PHPUnit 8.5.

Comment: Check for a 401/403 response code.

Comment: Show some code, in general feature tests in Laravel does not throw exceptions

Comment: Also tried assertStatus 401/403 but it doesn't help. Looks like after exception it doesn't read any code.

`$reply = create('App\Reply');
$this->delete('replies/' . $reply->id);`

Create is a helper function that creates a reply along with a thread.

Comment: You still have not shown some code, it is hard to help when we cant see the whole test

Comment: These two lines are whole test.

Comment: $this->delete('replies/' . $reply->id)->assertStatus(401);

Comment: @mohammad.kaab, as I said it doesn't read any code after `$this->delete('replies/' . $reply->id);`so it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->get('/routeThatRequiresAuthentication');

$this->assertGuest();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/** @test */
public function unauthenticated_user_cannot_access_protected_routes()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $this->expectException('Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException');

    $this->getJson('/api/user'); //This route is protected with auth:api
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$this->deleteJson('replies/' . $reply->id);`. It will return json response instead of throwing an exception. You can then call `->assertStatus(401);` on it

Comment: Still throws Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException but thanks a lot for reply

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you can use the `auth()` helper method to get the currently authenticated user as below. If no authenticated user is found, it will return null. And this is what you can assert to check for unauthenticated.

```
$this->assertNull(auth()->user());
```

I believe this will also work:

```
$this->assertFalse(auth()->check());
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.